# How to toggle the background colour of a div element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle the background colour of a div element but my code doesn't work. I wrote the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $on_off = true;
  $('div.hot').on('click', function($on_off){
    if($on_off){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    else{
      $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
    $on_off = !$on_off;
    });
});
```

I don't understand why this wouldn't work. 
Thanks!

Comment: `$on_off` in the event listener is the event, not the variable you are declaring above the event listener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Remove argument from `on` handler as first argument is `event-object` which is always evaluated as `true`(`Boolean({})===true`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $on_off = true;
  $('div.hot').on('click', function() {
    if ($on_off) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
    $on_off = !$on_off;
  });
});
```

**Simplified code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $on_off = true;
  $('div.hot').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', $on_off ? 'red' : 'yellow');
    $on_off = !$on_off;
  });
});
```

Comment: i understand that my code will work on removing the argument but why wouldn't it work if I write it as: function(event, $on_off) ?

Comment: First argument in `on` handler is `event-object` no matter what name you give.

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers receives an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) Object when they are invoked but you are expecting another variable (`$on_off`) which doesn't exist inside event handler. So `$on_off` variable that you have passed to event handler is in fact an object which will be automatically created and passed to the event handlers when they are invoked. This object is commonly referred to as `event` or `e`. This object contains necessary information about event that is actually happened. To use `$on_off` variable you don't need to pass it to event handler explicitly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $on_off = true;

  $('div.hot').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if($on_off){
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    else{
      $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
    $on_off = !$on_off;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hot">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be better served if you add two classes `red` and `yellow`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.hot').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('red')
        $(this).switchClass('red','yellow');
    else
        $(this).switchClass('yellow','red');
  });
});
```

and just initialise your div with